# Failure to find org.geoserver:gs-wms:jar:2.5.2

Tags: java, maven, repository, pom.xml, geoserver

I have failed to build a maven web application because of one dependency `gs-wms` from geoserver.

Here is pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>gs-wms</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <!-- xerces incompatible with JasperReports -->
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Error returned is

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project my-app:web:jar:1.5.0: Failure to find org.geoserver:gs-wms:jar:2.5.2 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I tried to use mirror in `settings.xml` as follows

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">


<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <mirrorOf>Maven repository</mirrorOf>
        <id>mirror-for-geoserver-gs-wms</id>
        <name>Repo for old geoserver version</name>
        <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geoserver/gs-wms/</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>mainProfile</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>Maven repository</id>
                <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>repo-for-geoserver-gs-wms</id>
                <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geoserver/gs-wms/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>Maven repository</id>
                <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>repo-for-geoserver-gs-wms</id>
                <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geoserver/gs-wms/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>mainProfile</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

But I got the error

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project my-app:web:jar:1.5.0: Failure to find org.geoserver:gs-wms:jar:2.5.2 in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geoserver/gs-wms/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of mirror-for-geoserver-gs-wms has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: If you look at that version in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geoserver/gs-wms/2.5.2 you'll see that it is in a different repo: https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/

However this server does not exist. There may be later versions in https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/

Comment: @tgdavies Do you mean that i can't get that version?

Comment: There may be ways to get it. Perhaps you could build it from source and put it in your local repo.

Comment: Can you give me some ideas on how to achieve that

Comment: You'd need to find the repository where the source is, check out the tag for that version and `man install` it. But maybe a later version will work?

Comment: 2.5 is very, very, old - we are currently on 2.17 - so it may be time to upgrade

Comment: @TurtonThanks for your response. But you said that currently is v2.17? Why is it behind 2.5?

Comment: I managed to solve this error, i used mirrors to get the correct version